# Problema con la exportacion de funciones NodeJS y Express

Tags: nodejs, express

Estoy haciendo un proyecto personal con NodeJS. Estoy teniendo problemas con los export.

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "trastos",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-flash": "^0.0.2",
    "express-session": "^1.18.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "pug": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

routes.js

```js
import express from 'express'
import * as gestionBBDD from '../models/databaseModel.js'
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
...

module.exports = router
```

index.js

```js
...
import * as regularRouter from './routes/routes.js'
app.use('/', regularRouter);
...
```

Me está arrojando el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and './package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

Si comento el module.exports = router y establezco la constante de router como export, el mensaje varía:

```
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Module
```

Mi version de Node es v20.10.0 (bajo Debian). ¿Qué puede estar mal?

Comment: En el archivo `package.json`, proba sacando `"type": "module"` o cambiando a `"type": "commonjs"`

Comment: Hola! Lo tenía antes así, pero entonces hacía todo con requires. Ahora me salta un mensaje así: ` Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.`